# Magento - Custom CSS Path defaulting to 'Base'

Tags: php, magento

I've created a custom theme for Magento and I have changed the following settings in System>Configuration>Design...

- Current Package Name: default
- Translations: diamondbladedealer
- Templates: diamondbladedealer
- Skin (Images / CSS): diamondbladedealer
- Layout: diamondbladedealer
- Default: diamondbladedealer

I've also cleared the cache manually and disabled it. Though it appears on the page [here](http://diamondblades.hingeweb.com/magento/index.php/), it's still trying to load css from base/default as opposed to default/diamondbladedealer.

I'm not sure how to proceed. Can someone give me an idea of how to fix this?

Comment: have you added skin/css path from admin under system configuration -> general -> design. ?

Comment: Have you tried to flush the CSS/JS cache (button at the bottom of the cache page, not in the table) ?

Comment: you might be to forget to add css in header using xml in your theme layout xml

Comment: I did clear the cache and the CSS is actually found in the source. The problem is it's being called from http://diamondblades.hingeweb.com/magento/skin/frontend/base/default/css/app.css instead of http://diamondblades.hingeweb.com/magento/skin/frontend/default/diamondbladedealer/css/app.css

Comment: It appears the file was in the wrong directory on the server and so it 404'ed and somehow defaulted to base/default. Thanks guys!

Comment: if you are using local.xml then you have to add in head <layout>
<default>
 <reference name="head">
 <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/skin.css</name><params/></action>